# How to get predictions for datarange greater than test dataset daterange using auto_timeseries model.predict?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, prediction, forecast

I was using auto_timeseries model to find the best fit for my timeseries dataset. While doing predictions
as below

```
predictions = model.predict( testdata = can be either a dataframe or an integer standing for the forecast_period, model = 'best' or any other string that stands for the trained model )
```

The parameter **testdata** only gives predictions for the datarange present in the test dataset, even on giving bigger integer value for **testdata** and in documentation its given as below.

> testdata (required): It can be either a dataframe containing test data or you can use an integer standing for the forecast_period (you want).

So is it possible to get predictions for datarange greater than the daterange of test dataset in auto_timeseries model?

Thankyou!